# Setting a Ranged Time Then Updating When Moved to Another Time Slot Using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

Sorry if my title was a bit vague. I'm having a tough time articulating my question into a title.

What I'm trying to do is have a form that dynamically creates an HTML table (easy). One of the elements in my form asks for a time duration, e.g. 1PM to 2PM or 1.20PM to 1.56PM (still easy).

Now, I want to create a drag and drop element that allows me to move rows up or down. However, when I do that, I want the times to adjust accordingly.

Example: I have three rows. ROW A has a time range set from 2PM to 2.45PM. ROW B has a time range set from 2.45PM to 3.15PM. ROW C has a time range from 3.15PM to 3.30PM.

If I were to move ROW C to above ROW A, ROW C's new time should be 2PM to 2.15PM. Then ROW A's should adjust to 2.15PM to 3PM. And ROW B should now be 3PM to 3.30PM.

Because users could assign any hour range, the only logic I could think would be to list out all 24 hours using a 2,400 number system. E.g. instead of 1PM, it would be 1,300. Then using logic, I'd convert 1,300 into 1:00PM for the user to see. 501 would convert into 5:01AM. Etc.

Surely there's a cleaner way to do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you simply want to sort by time ?

Comment: I want to essentially create a schedule of rows each with a sequence of times.

Then modify the form afterward by reorganizing rows with click and drag (I can do that). So you aren't sorting by time. Time is changing based on the order of rows. And the original times were set by a user.

I just can't picture the logic to update times like in my example. Except with my original idea which seems far more complicated than it needs to be. So I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: do you just want to change their order ? or also want to change the time ? like - will the first row always be a certain time ?

Comment: Change the time as well based on the order of rows. So say ROW A is the first row and has a start time of 1PM and an end time of 2PM. And ROW B has a start time of 2PM and end time of 3PM. If I move ROW A to the first row it should now have a time of 1PM and an end time of 2PM. ROW A would then have a time of 2PM and 3PM. However, the difficult is when rows have varying start and end times like in my previous examples. Some are 30 mins long, some 15, some an hour, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest choosing the maximum precision you'll need for your application (be it minutes or seconds or something more precise) and representing all your data using those precision values. You can give each row a duration in units of whatever precision you chose. Assuming you're not worried about the date, you can also represent your start time in the same precision, treating midnight the day before as 0. So, from your example, if your precision is minutes, 2 p.m. = 14 (2 p.m. in 24-hour time) * 60 (minutes per hour) = 840, and your overall start time is 840. Row A has a duration of 45 (minutes), B is 30, C is 15 - your rows look like an array of [45, 30, 15].

Now to calculate the start and end times for each row it's just regular arithmetic: take the end time of the previous row (or the overall start time, in the case of the first row) and add the row's duration to it to get the end time. E.g. Row A starts at 840 and ends at 885 (840 start + 45 duration). Row B starts at 885 and ends at 915. Row C starts at 915 and ends at 930.

To convert those numbers back into HH:MM, divide by 60 and truncate to get the HH (in 24-hour; you'll have to do a little computation for a.m./p.m.) and take the modulo 60 to get the minutes. E.g. The Row C start time of 915 works out to

```
Math.floor(915 / 60) // => 15 (that's 15 hours, so 3 p.m.) 
915 % 60 // => 15 (15 minutes)
```

Put those together and you get 15:15 in 24-hour time, or 3:15 p.m., which is, as expected, what you originally wrote as the start time for Row C.

If Row C gets moved to the front, it now starts at 840 (the overall start time) and ends at 855 (840 + 15 minute duration), Row A starts at 855 and ends at 900, Row B starts at 900 and ends at 930.

If you do need to worry about the date, you may want to consider using time since the epoch to keep a handle on your overall starting point, and going from there.

Comment: I was on the right path, but thanks for taking my theory and turning it into an answer. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Took so long, i had a headech - went to bed after taking 2 Excedrin then got up decided i want to do it.

I hope this will do,

```
    var rows = [
    {id : "1", start:1, end:4, content : "1", dur : 3},
    {id : "2", start:4, end:7, content : "2", dur : 3},
    {id : "3", start:7, end:11, content : "3", dur : 4},
    {id : "4", start:11, end:15, content : "4", dur : 4},
    {id : "5", start:15, end:16, content : "5", dur : 1},
]
    , startIndex , endIndex;

function buildTable(){
    var i = 0, l = rows.length, container = $('#tableHolder tbody'), tmpHold;
    container.html('');
    for(i; i<l; i++){
    container.append('<tr><td>From: '+ rows[i].start +' To:' + rows[i].end+ ' content : ' + rows[i].content + ' duration : ' + rows[i].dur +'</td></tr>');
    }
}
buildTable();
$( "#tableHolder tbody" ).sortable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        startIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ui.item[0].parentNode.childNodes, ui.item[0]);
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        endIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ui.item[0].parentNode.childNodes, ui.item[0])

        if(startIndex !== endIndex){
            rebuildArray (startIndex, endIndex)
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();

function rebuildArray(startIndex,endIndex){
    var tempVal, arrMiddle, arrStart, arrEnd, i, l, starTime;
    tempVal = rows[startIndex];
    arrMiddle =  [tempVal];
    rows.splice(startIndex,1);
    arrStart =  rows.slice(0,endIndex);
    arrEnd = rows.slice(endIndex,rows.length+1);
    rows = arrStart.concat(arrMiddle, arrEnd);
    i = 0; 
    l = rows.length;
    starTime = getEarlierStartTime();
    for(i; i<l;i++){
        starTime = updateMyTime(rows[i], starTime);
    }
    buildTable();
}

function getEarlierStartTime(){
    var i, l, earliest;
    i = 0; 
    l = rows.length;
    for(i; i<l;i++){
        if(!earliest) earliest = rows[i].start;
        if(rows[i].start < earliest) earliest = rows[i].start;
    }

    return earliest;
}

function updateMyTime(row, startTime){
    row.start = startTime;
    row.end = startTime+row.dur;
    return row.end;
}
```

Should be working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xgv0rc68/6/ - did not test it too much.

What it does, wherever you drop the row it picks the start time, of of that row, if then adds to that start time the dropped row's duration and use that as the start time of the next row and then add to the next row's start time it's duration .... etc and re build the whole table.

Comment: Sorry for making you pop pills! This is insanely useful, far more than I had hoped for. Thanks for actually coding it in your example. Combining alexcavalli's answer with yours is exactly what I need to move forward with my little project. Your code actually has a few pieces I'll need to spend time researching. I got a little lost but that's due to my junior learnings. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: well i am happy i could help. if you have any questions let me know

Comment: Neta - Your example was built off an array. What if I'm dynamically creating a table? I can't seem to figure out how to reorder everything with a table. Unless, would you put all the form fields into an array then iterate on that like your example? Thanks for any guidance!